# run a script at 7am each morning that adds up the rain from the previous 24 hours

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with up-to-the-minute weather parameters.  I need to run a script at 7am each morning that adds up the rain from the previous 24 hours (7am-7am).

The table header for date column is LogDateTime and it is formatted YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.  The header for the rainfall column is TodayRainSoFar and is formatted #.##

Rough code to get today's rain should be something like:

```
Select TodayRainSoFar
From 'monthly'
WHERE LogDateTime Like '(current date, but I can't get anything to work here) 07:00:00'
```

Rough code to get yesterday's rain from 7am to 11:59pm should be something like:

```
Select TodayRainSoFar
From 'monthly'
WHERE LogDateTime Like '(current date minus 1, but I can't get anything to work here) 23:59:00'

minus

Select TodayRainSoFar
From 'monthly'
WHERE LogDateTime Like '(current date - 1, but I can't get anything to work here) 07:00:00'
```

Please let me know if anything else should be included to assist.  I know basic code (and of course can Google), but everything else about this db is automated and was not set up by me.

Comment: Please post some rows of data from your database as a table and the required output

Comment: "`The table header for date column is ... formatted YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.`" That is a fundamental misunderstanding of how SQL dates work. Assuming a sane table schema, the column is **NOT** formatted that way in the table. It actually has a _binary_ format. What you see is just how the query tool displays the data for you.

Comment: Joel, thank you.  Again, novice at this, but I did not realize that I was understanding incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

To get the sum use the [`sum()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregation function. To limit the timestamps of the records use the date arithmetic provided by [`date_add()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add). The current day can be obtained with [`curdate()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate).

```
SELECT sum(todayrainsofar)
       FROM monthly
       WHERE logdatetime >= date_add(date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL -1 DAY), INTERVAL 7 HOUR)
             AND logdatetime < date_add(curdate(), INTERVAL 7 HOUR);
```

Comment: thank you.  It does pull a number, however it says we had 130.49" of rain :-D
It is currently 9pm, so of course not running at the time I mentioned, but obviously the value is high (correct is about 2").

Comment: Your question was about how to code the "date time" logic for your "LogDateTime" field. We don't have any way of knowing what value is in "todayrainsofar" or how it would sum. Try dividing your summed answer by 60 and see if that makes more sense, though.

Comment: Understood.  I took the provided code and edited it for 7pm (`interval 19 hour` I would assume...) and it came up with about 700" (695.87").  Whereas there has been 0.38".  Only math that could get me there was divide by 60, then by 30.  Obviously I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', CURRENT_DATE(), '07:00:00')
```

should give you your date at 7 am like this: '2018-07-22 07:00:00'

To get the previous day, just do a DATE_SUB like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', (DATE_SUB((CURRENT_DATE()) , INTERVAL 1 DAY)), '07:00:00')
```

That should give you '2018-07-21 07:00:00' -- it does for me. 
Then, do the same code but put '23:59:59' in place of '07:00:00'.
You should then use an "=" operator instead of "LIKE" if you're looking for equality.
For example "WHERE LogDateTime = (concat_ws(' ', current_date(), '07:00:00')).

If you're wanting yesterday's rain from 7am to 11:59pm, I would use a "BETWEEN", in some manner like this:

```
    WHERE LogDateTime BETWEEN (concat_ws(' ', current_date(), '07:00:00')) AND
(CONCAT_WS(' ', (DATE_SUB((CURRENT_DATE()) , INTERVAL 1 DAY)), '23:59:59') )
```

See if this works for you.  Oh, I want to add one more tip if I may: using column functions (like CONCAT and DATE_SUB) in a WHERE clause is not something you want to do on large sets of data because there's really no way for the MySQL optimizer to figure out the best access path. In this situation, I think it'll work fine.

Comment: Using `BEETWEEN`, hence including both endpoints, will use a datapoint, if at the end or beginning of the period, twice for subsequent days. That may give a wrong picture (It's possible, that the sum of the sums for all periods won't be equal to (but in fact larger than) the sum of all datapoints).

Comment: Good point, thanks. I see your ">=" and "<" code below. It looks good. In fact, your whole answer is much more concise than mine!